# Is $ f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln x},\quad x\in(0,\,\frac{1}{2}] $ Hölder continuous?

Tags: analysis

> Is
>   $$
> f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln x},\quad x\in(0,\,\frac{1}{2}]
> $$
>   Hölder continuous?

That is, are there constant $C>0$ and $\alpha>0$ such that 
$$
|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\leq C|x_1-x_2|^\alpha \text{  ?}
$$

Since $f$ is bounded and continuous on $(0,\,\frac{1}{2}]$, I can only prove it's uniformly continuous. But I don't know how to handle
$$
\bigg|\frac{\ln x_1-\ln x_2}{\ln x_1\,\ln x_2}\bigg|\leq C|x_1-x_2|^\alpha.
$$

Comment: It is not Holder continuous. See fourth Example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition

Comment: Thanks. Can you give a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there exist $C,\alpha>0$, such that for all $x_1,x_2\in(0,\dfrac{1}{2}]$, we have  $\lvert\dfrac{1}{\log x_1}-\dfrac{1}{\log x_2}\rvert\leq C\lvert x_1-x_2\rvert^{\alpha}$. Let $x_1\to0$, we have $\lvert\dfrac{1}{\log x_2}\rvert\leq C\lvert x_2\rvert^\alpha$, which is $\lvert \dfrac{1}{x_2^\alpha\log x_2}\rvert\leq C$. Taking $x_2\to0$, by L'hopital rule, we see that $\lvert \dfrac{1}{x_2^\alpha\log x_2}\rvert\to +\infty$, a contradiction.